# mvc custom validation min price

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a project. And I need a custom validation for find minimum price. Now first off all my model is in here;

```
public class ReservationModel
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public Guid ApartId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Guest { get; set; }
    public string ApartName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string ApartDesc { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public double MinAmount { get; set; }
    public string ApartImage { get; set; }
    public string CheckInTime { get; set; }
    public string CheckOutTime { get; set; }
    public int DayOfReservation { get; set; }
    public int ReservationGuestNumber { get; set; }




}
```

I want to use this validation in MinAmount. I have dynamic prices. For example apart price 300 USD. I want to MinAmount Value is must be 300 X 25 /100 = 75 USD. Validation error fire is If client write 50 USD or under 75 USD. So How can create My custom MinPriceAttribute??? Thanks for kindly replies.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create your custom filter. 
You can find some tips here [mvc custom filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters)

[Video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYbsHj04Cb8)